# how does the answer of the colliding blocks puzzle change if we add more blocks with mass proportional to each other?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In this video by [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs) talks about when you have a block with a mass equal to $\alpha$ and the other block with a mass equal to $\alpha\times100^{\space d-1}$ moving at a constant velocity towards a wall, the amount of collisions will be the smallest whole number with the first $d$ digits of $\pi$. *(with what I understand about the guide lines if I have 2 related questions I must split them into two different questions rather than making it into one, so when I post the other question it will be
**Here**)*

My question is when you have $n$ blocks where $n\geq 3$ blocks with masses $\alpha, \alpha \times100^{d-1}, \alpha \times100^{2d-2}, \dots, \alpha \times100^{nd-d-n+1}$ equally spread apart with the most massive block going a constant speed toward a wall how many collisions will there be? If there is no easy way to find it for any $n$ what about 3 blocks?

###### If there is something in my question I can improve on please comment what I can improve on.